# Does microprofile openapi have synonym of allowableValues in swagger?

Tags: swagger, openapi, microprofile

I am working on a Java application. With io.swagger.v3, we can list all acceptable values of the parameter by using  `@Parameter(description = "Level of detail in result", schema = @io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.media.Schema(allowableValues = {"low", "high", "debug" }))` so that only "low", "high", "debug" are allowed. Now I was asked to use org.eclipse.microprofile.openapi instead of swagger. However, I cannot find how to achieve this with oepnapi. Could someone help me plz?